# Splash screen not changing for iphone 4 in xcode 5.0.1

Tags: ios, splash-screen, launchimage

I am working on the latest xcode i.e. version 5.0.1. I have set the launch images for both iphone 4 and iphone 5. Xcode renames the images as Default (for iPhone 4) and Default~iphone (for iPhone 5). But when i run the application on 3.5 inch simulator, it shows the launch image for iphone 5. I have tried clean build but that did not solve my problem. How can i resolve my issue?

Comment: Are you using asset catalogs?

Comment: No I am not using asset catalogs.

Comment: Use asset catalogs (very easy to enable, there is an option next to the placeholder you set the default images) and add the images to the asset catalog. The issue may be that you have not included non-retina 3.5 inch images and you run the non-retina 3.5" simulator.

Comment: My application has to be compatible with iOS 5.1 as well. And I am developing on the 6.1 SDK. Would Asset catalogs cause my application to be incompatible with those?

Comment: No, asset catalogs are just a way to organize your assets. It is an xcode 5 feature and has nothing to do with the base sdk that you use in your project.

Comment: Added as an answer. You can vote if you'd like.

Comment: The latest version is 5.0.2 by the way ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use asset catalogs (very easy to enable, there is an option next to the placeholder you set the default images) and add the images to the asset catalog. The issue may be that you have not included non-retina 3.5 inch images and you run the non-retina 3.5" simulator.

(Asset catalogs are features of Xcode 5 they do not depend on the SDK, so you can use them and build with older SDKs).